# Aligning a content in center within a class using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hello fellow developers community.

Im pretty new to using CSS, currently when I increase the width of my class .form-search to i.e. 105% in my CSS, then this moves the search bar to the right, I want to keep the search bar in the center regardless of what width size % I do, is there something I do in CSS to keep it in center regardless of the width size?

```
My current CSS code is below:

    @media (max-width: 600px)
    .form-search {
        width: 108%;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

My HTML below.

```
<form method="GET" action="/search/" role="search" class="form-search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="q" class="sr-only">
      Type to search the test services online
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Type to test Services Online" value="" title="Type to test Services Online">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" title="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: does `.form-search` have parent?

Comment: Please tell us more. You need to create a [mcve]

Comment: use `text-align:center`

Comment: can u plz send the html code?

Comment: if it does, add CSS code to that parent `text-align: center`.

Comment: @Shizukura it still does the same thing, what you mean Parent?

Comment: @Waq do you mean [this?](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7YRWO9TSKU4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.. I think in your css did'nt the open the curly brace..

```
.input-group {
    text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.form-search { 
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there something I do in CSS to keep it in center regardless of the
>   width size?

Yes. Two declarations in CSS (using `flexbox`):

```
.form-search {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This will ensure the children of `.form-search` remain in the center of `.form-search`, regardless of their own width and regardless of the width of `.form-search`.